# Pause and resume multiprocessing process python object

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have issue where I need to create python process thread using multiprocessing
And any give of time to pause it - and later to resume it - the issue is this logic can be execute on multi thread.

I try to use Event but I’m new to python multiprocessing.

This is the code I create but the pause / resume not working - any help please :) ?

```
import multiprocessing

def control_process(process):
    """
    Receive a process object as an argument and provides the ability
    to pause and resume the process.
    """
    while True:
        command = input("Enter 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume, or 'q' to quit: ")
        print(command)
        if command == "p":
            process.set()
        elif command == "r":
            process.clear()
        elif command == "q":
            process.terminate()
            break
import time

def my_function():
    while True:
        print("Hello, world!")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)
    p.start()
    
    control_process(p)
```

the output should be

```
Start thread 1 ....
puase thread 1 ....
start thread 2 ....
Thread 2 ......
Thread 2 ......
End Thread 2 ....
End thread 1 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a [multiprocessing.Event](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) for this, basically you would pass one to the child and the controlling thread and have it `set` it to resume and `clear` it to pause the execution as follows.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def control_process(process, pause_event):
    """
    Receive a process object as an argument and provides the ability
    to pause and resume the process.
    """
    while True:
        command = input("Enter 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume, or 'q' to quit: ")
        print(command)
        if command == "p":
            pause_event.clear()
        elif command == "r":
            pause_event.set()
        elif command == "q":
            process.terminate()
            break

def my_function(pause_event, event_started):
    event_started.set()  # signal parent that it has started execution
    while pause_event.wait():  # returns True if pause_event is set
        print("Hello, world!")
        time.sleep(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pause_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    started_event = multiprocessing.Event()  # to know when the child started execution
    # consider making this next process daemon for guaranteed cleanup
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function, args=(pause_event, started_event))
    p.start()

    started_event.wait(timeout=5)  # to fix window's buggy terminal
    control_process(p, pause_event)
```

the use of `started_event` is important if you are using `input` on windows as it locks the whole terminal, which prevents the child from spawning until the `input` function ends. (try setting `pause_event.set()` in main process before starting the child, it won't work without it)

Answer (score 0):

To make "p" (pause) and "r" (resume) work you can use *multiprocessing.Event*  `pause_event` instead of process.

Also there's no need to print the command again since u can see it on the command input.

Try the follwing code:

```
import multiprocessing,time
    
def my_function(pause_event):
    while True:
        if not pause_event.is_set():
            print("Hello, world!")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pause_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    pause_event.clear()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function, args=(pause_event,))
    p.start()
    
    while True:
        command = input("Enter 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume, or 'q' to quit: ")
        if command == "p":
            pause_event.set()
        elif command == "r":
            pause_event.clear()
        elif command == "q":
            p.terminate()
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)
    p.start()
    
    control_process(p)
```

Finally if you want your output to be as you wish, you should add the corresponing prints for your threads.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).